# What is the equivalent of a timer tick of 30 minutes?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a  timer tick that I would like to kick off my backgroundworker every 30 minutes. What is the equivalent value of 30 minutes for a timer tick?

Below follows the code:

```
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        _timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);              
        _timer.Enabled = true;                       
        _timer.Start();       

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _ticks++;
        if (_ticks == 15)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            _ticks = 0;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if this is the best way or if anyone has a better suggestion.

Comment: Is this C#? Please tag and title your question properly.

Comment: hello BoltClock sorry about that its done :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) property of a timer is specified in milliseconds, not ticks.

Therefore, for a timer which fires every 30 minutes, simply do:

```
// 1000 is the number of milliseconds in a second.
// 60 is the number of seconds in a minute
// 30 is the number of minutes.
_timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 30;
```

However, I'm not clear what the `Tick` event you use is. I think you mean [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer_events.aspx)?

**EDIT** As CodeNaked makes clear, you are talking about the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdh6857z.aspx), not the [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8.aspx). Luckily, my answer applies to both :)

Finally, I don't understand why you maintain a count (`_ticks`) within your `timer_Tick` method. You should re-write it as follows:

```
void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi RB well the tick just counts - and when it reaches a ceratin value it kicks off the backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); are u suggesting this should be done another way?

Comment: The OP is probably using the [WinForms Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx).

Comment: @CodeNaked Thanks :) Luckily, my answer still applies!!

Comment: Hi There RB - im not too familiar with the timer as yet, are u suggesting that using the elapsed event to kick off the  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); ? - fanx :D

Comment: update - hi RB - i tested it and seems work fine thank you very muc :D

Answer (score 6):

To make the code more readable, you can use the `TimeSpan` class:

```
_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get the question well. But if u just want the interval of 30 minutes then give
timer1.interval = 1800000;

// There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond (Dont forget this )

Comment: Mil means thousand believe it or not.
There are 1,000 milliseconds in a second. 1,000 millimetres in one meter.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

[STAThread]

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Timer t = new Timer(1800000); // 1 sec = 1000, 30 mins = 1800000 
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
    t.Start(); 
}

private static void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
// do stuff every 30  minute
}
```